# Upload to and download from Skydrive account from a WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, onedrive

I am trying to list the folders and files in Skydrive account from a desktop app. I have used web browser control and oauth for authentication. To be able to upload and download files from the account, Skydrive API can be used. But it is supported only by the Windows store and phone apps, and not the desktop apps. Can anyone please provide some suggestions regarding how to solve this issue?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826529.aspx shows how desktop apps can connect to and use SkyDrive. In fact there is a whole WPF application sample built on that page.

Comment: @PreetSangha Thanks for the immediate response. I followed the same page for authentication of user and displaying details pertaining to the profile. But it doesn't explain anything about uploading and downloading files and folders from the account.